# How to get what class a generic collection holds?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a list

```
type
  TMyList = class(TList<TMyClass>);
```

I want to get from a procedure of this list the ClassName of the class this list holds, in this case `TMyClass`. I can use an attribute but I want to avoid this solution.

Comment: @David, aha. I've seen that `<TMyClass>` just the first time the question was posted. Then the OP changed it in the grace period to the form before your edit, so I though it was just changed to a half generic, half non-generic question without thinking about SO formatter. Silly me...

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want exactly.  You declared the class to explicitly hold `TMyClass`, so why do you need to discovery that? And do you need the class **type** as a `TClass`, or the class **name** as a string?  Please be more specific about your actual requirements, and maybe show an example of what you are actually trying to solve.

Comment: The declaration is like this: TMyClass = class , TMyObjectList<T: class> = class(TObjectList<T>) , TMyList = class(TMyObjectList<TMyClass>). I only store classes and I wanted a way from the base collection class to get the class name stored inside, David's implementation is exactly what I needed. Sorry for missing the proper declaration of the types used and argh editing the question here to add that makes me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can do that very easily with a stock `TList<T>`. You could extend `TList<T>` to expose the class of the element like this:

```
type
  TMyList<T: class> = class(TList<T>)
  private
    class function GetElementType: TClass; static;
  public
    class property ElementType: TClass read GetElementType;
  end;

class function TMyList<T>.GetElementType: TClass;
begin
  Result := T;
end;
```

This forces your list to contain classes. If you wanted to be more general, and cover lists of types other than just classes then I think you'd need to delve into RTTI. In fact RTTI would provide you a way to obtain the element class without modifying the class. For example:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Generics.Collections, System.Rtti;

type
  TMyObject = class
  end;

var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  ListType: TRttiInstanceType;
  Method: TRttiMethod;
  ReturnType: TRttiType;

begin
  ListType := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TList<TMyObject>)) as TRttiInstanceType;
  Method := ListType.GetMethod('First');
  ReturnType := Method.ReturnType;
  Writeln(ReturnType.ToString);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Why declare `GetElementType()` to return a `TClass` instead of a `T`? Or why not declare a public `type` declaration in the class that maps to `T`, instead of declaring a method?

Comment: @RemyLebeau First question, why not return T? Because a T is an instance. Second question, declaring a type would make sense.

Comment: Ok, then return `class of T` instead of the general `TClass`, at least.

Comment: Actually I tried that, and if you try to declare `class of T` you get **E2021 Class type required**. Check it out. Seems like it ought to work. Maybe needs a QC report.

Comment: What about `public type TListItemClass = class of T; function GetElementType: TListItemClass;` ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that is the type declaration that gives E2021. Try it out. Do you think I should submit a QC report?